# PostgreSQL table backup from node.js(express)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, backup

How to create full Postgresql database backup and separated table from node.js (express/loopback)?
I didn't find any solution to sole it...
Any information...
I'm interested in sql dump, because there are 2 "big" tables (~40.00. raws / ~ 30 columns) and several tables-dictionary.

Comment: Your question has no focus on the problem... You ask how to do a full back-up? You ask how to back-up a single table? You ask how to export a table into inserts? You ask how to export data rows through HTTP?

Comment: I apologize for inexperience. I'm looking for a way to do a full back-up of database (with foreign keys, etc.) and insert into. For example.Every week, nodejs will create back-up of entire database and every day (or from admin panel (web-client) by special button) create sql(insert into) back-up.

Answer (score 1):

A simple answer, although maybe not what you're looking for: you can make a `package.json` script which uses shell commands (including the PostgreSQL built-in `pg_dump`):

```
"backup-db": "pg_dump YourDatabaseName | gzip > backups/database_backup.`date +%m-%d-%Y-%H-%M`.gz",
```